# How to get the points of a linear regression line?

Tags: regression, linear-model

I do a simple linear regression `mod <- lm(y ~ x)` and I plot its residuals, doing `plot(mod$residuals)`. Two questions:

1. I need to plot the line of the regression in the chart where I plotted the residuals, how can I do it?
2. I need to know the points of this line, because I should plot this line in another application, so I need those points (as a vector), how can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the points with

```
predict(mod)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use abline. In your case, just add

```
abline(mod)
```

Comment: ok thanks! what about the points of that line ? How can I get them?

Comment: As long as you have mod stored, you don't need the points. But you can get them with coef(mod), I believe

Comment: yes I know but i have to save the data (the list of points) how can i calculate them? is there a function?

Comment: You don't need a list of points. Just the coefficients; that's enough to plot a line.